# Emulate iMovie PIP exchange effect in Final Cut Pro X

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, imovie

I'm exporting a project from iMovie to Final Cut Pro X.

Not all tracks are exported properly, mainly the pip tracks.

What I want to do is to re-make in FCPX the same pip effect that in iMovie is named "exchange" (or something like this, my version is not in english).

Is there some fast way to to that in FCPX or I have to play with the keyframes each time?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create the effect in Motion.  I'm not sure what the iMovie effect looks like, but I use this technique on a daily basis. In my setup, there are actually six separate effects; left_panel_in, left_panel_static_, left_panel_out, right_panel_in, right_panel_static, right_panel_out.  This allows me to go between a 1-up and 2-up configuration at any point in time, and to do so consistently throughout multiple projects.  If you need step by step instructions, I would be happy to assist once I'm sitting in front of a machine with Motion on it.

best, Jason.